# pyserial readlines() hangs for longer timeout values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyserial

I am using version 3.2.1 of python serial library on Windows 7, Python 2.7.13

Here is my code:

```
import serial
import os
import sys
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="commands")
parser.add_argument("command", help="command")
args = parser.parse_args()

s = serial.Serial('COM9', 230400, timeout=20, write_timeout=20)
cmdline = args.command + os.linesep
print s.write(cmdline)  
s.flush()
lines = s.readlines()
print "".join(lines)
s.close()
```

The issue is that this code works just fine when I set timeout=2 or timeout=3. But for larger values it just hangs and never terminates. Why so ?